# new Thread creation from a class gets delayed when there is huge data

Tags: java, multithreading, class, delay

There is a class which accepts data processes it and passes to a new thread for communicating with a thrid party URL. What I have observed is when there is huge data coming to my class say 150 messages, after all 150 messages are processed then new thread creation starts. Can anyone please help me to understand why new thread creation starts after processing all messages in class and not while processing each data..

```
public class classCallingNewThread {

    public static String someMethod(String a, String b) {
        result = "success";

        if(somecondition) {
            xmldata = create some xml data;
            Processxml px = new Processxml(xmldata);
        } else {
            result="fail";
        }

        return result;
    }
}

public class Processxml extends Thread {

    public Processxml(xmldata a) {
        this.start();
    }

    public void run() {
        make url connection with 3rd party with xmldata
        this.kill();
    }
}
```

Comment: Unclear. What programming language? (add tag?) And a code snippet would help...

Comment: Calling `this.start()` from within the constructor of a thread is a bad idea.  Google for "java" and "leaking this".

Comment: What is `this.kill()`?  That's not a `Thread` method.  And anyway, a thread dies as soon as its `run()` method returns.

Comment: The constructor for your `Processxml` class takes an argument, `a`, but it doesn't do anything with the argument.  Likewise your `someMethod(a, b)` doesn't do anything with `a` or `b`.  It looks like you've chopped a lot of stuff out of your code snippet.  Maybe you've cut out the part that would have give anybody a clue as to what's going wrong.

Comment: I get suspicious any time I see a thread with a `run()` method that does not loop, and my suspicion is confirmed when I see that the program creates a new thread each time X happens.  That is a very clear use-case for a _thread pool_ (e.g., `java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor`).  Creating and destroying threads is costly, and allowing hundreds of similar threads compete for system resources may slow things down.  A thread pool lets you queue up arbitrarily many _tasks_ to be executed by any one of a handful of long-lived threads.